# Problema con consulta symfony 3

Tags: symfony3, doctrine2

Tengo la siguiente situación, tengo 3 tablas.Por un lado tengo una lista de miembros ,una lista de cargos y otra tabla q muestra los cargos que han ido teniendo cada miembro en diferentes años.Lo que necesito es mostrar una vista con el listado de miembros con sus cargos actuales,o sea el último cargo que se le asignó. Desarrollo en symfony 3 y necesito alguna consulta en dql o querybuilder que me visualice lo que necesito.Les muestro las tablas con datos de ejemplo y como debería quedar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomando en cuenta la estructura de las tablas que propones, la consulta sería:

```
SELECT m.nombre,c.descripcion,cm.fecha_ini
FROM miembro AS m
    JOIN cargos_miembros AS cm
        ON m.id = cm.id_miembro
    JOIN cargos AS c
        ON cm.id_cargo = c.id
WHERE cm.id IN (
    SELECT MAX(cm.id) FROM cargos_miembros AS cm
    GROUP BY cm.id_miembro
)
```